# selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element:

Tags: selenium, webdriver, element

I'm trying to automatically generate lots of users on the webpage kahoot.it using selenium to make them appear in front of the class, however, I get this error message when trying to access the inputSession item (where you write the gameID to enter the game)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.kahoot.it")

gameID = driver.find_element_by_id("inputSession")
username = driver.find_element_by_id("username")

gameID.send_keys("53384")
```

This is the error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element:
{"method":"id","selector":"inputSession"}
```

Comment: how does the html look like?

Comment: You can check out the whole code from kahoot.it, but the relevant part is:
<form ng-submit="joinSession(gameId)" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">   <input id="inputSession" ios7fix="" class="username ng-pristine ng-valid" placeholder="Game pin" ng-model="gameId" type="tel" maxlength="6" shake="badGameId">   <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-greyscale join" blocking="" tap="joinSession(gameId)">Enter</button>  </form>

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Could be a race condition where the find element is executing before it is present on the page. Take a look at the [wait timeout documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html). Here is an example from the docs

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://somedomain/url_that_delays_loading")
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "myDynamicElement"))
    )
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: Need to update link. It appears to now be https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

Answer (score 56):

Looks like it takes time to load the webpage, and hence the detection of webelement wasn't happening. You can either use @shri's code above or just add these two statements just below the code `driver = webdriver.Firefox()`:

```
driver.maximize_window() # For maximizing window
driver.implicitly_wait(20) # gives an implicit wait for 20 seconds
```

Comment: Glad it helped you.. :)

Comment: Glad it helped you @Volatil3 . :)

Answer (score 6):

In my case, the error was caused by the element I was looking for being inside an `iframe`. This meant I had to change frame before looking for the element:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
    
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.google.co.uk/maps")

frame_0 = driver.find_element_by_class_name('widget-consent-frame')
driver.switch_to.frame(frame_0)

agree_btn_0 = driver.find_element_by_id('introAgreeButton')
agree_btn_0.click()
```

[Reddit source](https://www.reddit.com/r/selenium/comments/7yoxrc/hi_why_do_i_get_this_error_selenium_python/)

Answer (score 3):

You can also use below as an alternative to the above two solutions:

```
import time
time.sleep(30)
```

Comment: driver.implicitly_wait(30) is a better option because this sleep ALWAYS wait 30' (not only when need it)

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your browser did not read proper HTML texts/tags, use a delay function that'll help the page to load first and then get all tags from the page.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver.exe')
# load the page
driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/')
# use delay function to get all tags
driver.implicitly_wait(20)
# access tag
driver.find_element_by_name('username').send_keys(self.username)
```

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me (the try/finally didn't, kept hitting the finally/browser.close())

```
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('mywebsite.com')

username = None
while(username == None):
    username = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "username"))
    )
username.send_keys('myusername@email.com')
```

Answer (score 1):

Also for some, it may be due to opening the new tabs when clicking the button(not in this question particularly). Then you can switch tabs by command.

```
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1]) #for switching to second tab
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as you and this solution saved me:

```js
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'someid')))
```

Answer (score 0):

it just means the function is executing before button can be clicked. Example solution:

```
from selenium import sleep
# load the page first and then pause
sleep(3)
# pauses executing the next line for 3 seconds
```