# I can't seem to locate the input box element using Python/Selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium

I am trying to use Python to automate something.

I can't seem to locate the email input element with `driver.find_element_by_`. I tried so many different ways. I just want to be able to log into the website with Chromedriver.

```html
<div class="css-1ilyui9">
    <input type="email" required="" class="css-cgadzw" value="">
</div>
```

The email input box doesn't have any attributes. No name or id. Class is not unique. Password box has the same class.

This is what I have so far. I just want Python to log in for me and go to a certain page periodically but I am unable to send_key because I can't find the element. It keeps saying "element not found".

```py
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_path = r"C:\Users\peter\Desktop\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\peter\Desktop\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='email']")
```

**Error Code:**

```py
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: 
Message: no such element: 
Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@type='email']"}
  (Session info: chrome=78.0.3904.108)
```

Comment: What if you try `email = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//input[@type='email']")` then use `email[0]`?  *Also, unrelated to the issue, but you could use the variable here, `driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_path)`, no?

Comment: email = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//input[@type='email']") this works, but I can't send_keys.

Comment: did you try with`email[0].sendKeys()`?

Comment: check if your element is inside `iframe` or `frame`

Answer (score 2):

Try to use two identifiers in your selector:

```py
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='css-cgadzw'][@type='email']")
```

Also, you may need to put some wait in order to be able to see the element on page as refereed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27112731/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-unable-to-locate-ele)

Comment: Hey man, thanks for the input. I tried that... but same error codeselenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@class='css-cgadzw'][@type='email']"}
  (Session info: chrome=78.0.3904.108)

Comment: I will try adding the wait and see. Thanks :)