# Selenium Login failing - wrong ids?

Tags: python, selenium, authentication, arcgis

This is just a quick sanity check I'm hoping someone can put some eyes on.

Basically, I'm trying to log into this site (ArcGIS Online) with selenium: https://www.arcgis.com/home/signin.html?useLandingPage=true".

This is what the elements look like:
[image]

My code for the login looks like this:

```
user = driver.find_element_by_name("user_username")
password = driver.find_element_by_name("user_password")
user.clear()
user.send_keys(username)
password.clear()
password.send_keys(password)
driver.find_element_by_id("signIn").click()
```

In this case, I'm using the **ArcGIS login** option...not sure if I need to be activating that first? I'm assuming there's a step I'm missing here to get this to work.

The error I get currently is:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[name="user_username"]"}
```

Really appreciate any thoughts people have out there!

**EDIT:**

Updated code to this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.headless = True
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
url = "https://www.arcgis.com/home/signin.html?useLandingPage=true"
browser.get(url)

try:
    user = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "user_username"))
    )

    password = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "user_password"))
    )  

    signin = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "signIn"))
    ) 

    user.clear()
    user.send_keys(username)
    password.clear()
    password.send_keys(password)
    signin.click()

finally:
    browser.quit()
```

And now get this error:

```
TypeError: object of type 'WebElement' has no len()
```

Probably doing something wrong, will look deeper into the proper usage of wait functionality.

**FINAL EDIT:**

For anyone chancing upon this page, the solution was to wait for elements to load, make sure I was searching by IDs, and...make sure I had no typos! Below is a working scenario:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

username = "Hari"
password = "Seldon" 
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
url = "https://www.arcgis.com/home/signin.html?useLandingPage=true"
driver.get(url)
try:
    user = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "user_username")))
    passwd = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "user_password")))
    user.clear()
    user.send_keys(username)
    passwd.clear()
    passwd.send_keys(password)
    driver.find_element_by_id("signIn").click()  

finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: There seems to be a typo in the id. It's not ser_username. its user_username in the site.

Comment: My mistake I copied it over incorrectly. It's corrected now, but doesn't run with "user_username" either.

Comment: Try this Link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27112731/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-unable-to-locate-ele

Comment: That's helpful - I can see it does find the element now, but I get the error: "TypeError: object of type 'WebElement' has no len()"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wait for the elements to load on the page first:

```
user = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "user_username")))
password = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "user_password")))
user.clear()
user.send_keys("aaa")
password.clear()
password.send_keys("bbb")
driver.find_element_by_id("signIn").click()
```

You need these imports for the wait functionality:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```

Comment: Thanks - that's pretty much what I have now, but still no luck. It seems I was able to place the username/password but the sign-in click isn't working.

Comment: It seems to consistently be: "TypeError: object of type 'WebElement' has no len()"

Comment: I've just seen your edit. You have a variable called "password" which stores the webelement you will send_keys to. But what you are sending to that weblements is a variable having the same name. So you are trying to type in a webelement. Make sure to have different variable names and try again.

Comment: GOOD CATCH that was supppper sloppy of me sorry. Too much multitasking at the moment. I just updated the code and no errors!

Answer (score 1):

You are using `find_element_by_name` but using the value of id in the code. I changed it to `find_element_by_id` and it works. Code below:

```
user = browser.find_element_by_id("user_username")
password = browser.find_element_by_id("user_password")
user.clear()
user.send_keys(username)
password.clear()
password.send_keys(password)
browser.find_element_by_id("signIn").click()
```

Comment: Yep, tried that variation too but still get the exception: NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="user_username"]"}