# Unable to locate element in Selenium using Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, automation

here is the website link :

> https://www.milanuncios.com/anuncios/?fromSearch=1&fromSuggester=0&suggestionUsed=0

click on button called Llamar to see the the div

I've been trying to get the text of div.

To do this, I have to find this div element.

this is how the div element looks like in the browser :

[image]

***#Html Code***

```
<div class="telefonos">699771517</div>
```

I tried this two lines of python code:

***#Python Code***

```
TeleFonos = driver.find_element_by_class_name("telefonos")
print(TeleFonos.text)
```

but im always getting this error

***#Error***

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such
> element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css
> selector","selector":".telefonos"}

Do you know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your element is in the `iframe` so you need to switch into that `iframe` and then search. To do that use the below code -

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 60)
driver.get('https://www.milanuncios.com/anuncios/?fromSearch=1&fromSuggester=0&suggestionUsed=0')

wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[@data-testid=\"TcfAccept\"]"))).click()

try:
    All_Phone = wait.until(
        EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@onclick,\"phoneContactFromAdList\")]")))
    for phone in All_Phone:
        phone.click()
        iframe = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "ifrw")))
        driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
        print(wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "telefonos"))).text)
        driver.switch_to.default_content()
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(),\"Cerrar\")]").click()
except:
    pass
```

If it resolves your issue then please mark it as answer.

Comment: i tried your code but this error keep showing
Undefiened variable wait

Comment: There was some mistake, I have updated my code now please try again.

Comment: the wait 1 and 2 what they refer to ?

Comment: Is that code working and your problem solved? Read about Explicit wait in selenium.

Comment: its not working because ithe code is not printing telefonos.text always. it printed it only from few  elements. even all the elements is the same. i dont know why

Comment: Updated my answer, now you can extract all the Phone numbers in a page. This is the working code but if your need is bit different then i suggest you to modify code as per you requirement.

Comment: its not working properly but thanks anyway.
i really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that the element is not loaded at the time that Selenium is looking on the page?

I recommend looking at the suggestion here on using Selenium wait.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27112797/4352317

It might help triage the issue if the website in question is shared.

Comment: i have tried driver.implicitly_wait(30) but still the same error

Comment: i edit my Question to add website link i'll be greateful if you check it out

Comment: Looking back at the code, you are trying to access potentially a Psuedo Element because the ::before is included. This makes it difficult to access via DOM. Here is a Stack Overflow answer which may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59706267/4352317

Comment: I recommend selecting the "Llamar" button by using class="byCall" and then passing it a .click() method. Then wait. Then, you can access the div with the class 'telefonos'

Comment: thats what i did 
ToCallBtns = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("tracking-desktop-call-btn")
for x in range(len(ToCallBtns)):
    ToCallBtns[x].click()
    time.sleep(5)
    TeleFonos = driver.find_element_by_class_name("telefonos")
    print(TeleFonos.text)

Comment: @JoeThor that element is in the `iframe`. He has to switch the `iframe` first and then search for that element. The same mentioned in my answer.